# How to check if existing and then only extract the value?

Tags: jquery

For an ajax call  i get the response in following format

```
 var response = {
    "wwc_tag_names": [{
        "waterbreak_free": "waterbreak_free"
    }],
    "wwc_details": [{
        "generatedid": "2",
        "timer_value": "5",
        "warmup_value": "00:01:00",
        "cooldown_value": "00:01:00",
        "waterbreak_value": "00:02:30"
    }]
};
```

Sometimes the wwc_tag_names array consists of 1 - 4 key value pairs

I am trying to extract it this way

```
var ajaxresfortags = response.wwc_tag_names;
    if(ajaxresfortags.length>0)
    {
var warmuptag = ajaxresfortags[0].warmuptag;
var cooldowntag = ajaxresfortags[1].cooldowntag;
var waterbreaktag = ajaxresfortags[2].waterbreak_free;
var waterbreaktagpaid = ajaxresfortags[3].waterbreak_paid;
}
```

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9003/

If exists then only extract the warmuptag , cooldowntag , waterbreak_free , waterbreak_paid

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're trying to achieve to know what your issue is. You have an object containing the values you need, and you know what the keys are, so just retrieve them as needed.

Comment: As cooldowntag , warmuptag , waterbreak_paid does not exists , i am getting undefined in browser console

Comment: Because its in variable `ajaxres` and not `ajaxresfortags`

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing wrong variable to get warmuptag , cooldowntag , waterbreak_free , waterbreak_paid. You should be using ajaxres and not ajaxresfortags:

```
if(ajaxresfortags.length > 0)
{
 var ajaxResDetailsData = ajaxres[0];
 var warmuptag = ajaxResDetailsData.warmuptag;
 var cooldowntag = ajaxResDetailsData.cooldowntag;
 var waterbreaktag = ajaxResDetailsData.waterbreak_free;
 var waterbreaktagpaid = ajaxResDetailsData.waterbreak_paid;
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zqwphc7v/)**